# Cyclomatic complexity in dotCover report in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, cyclomatic-complexity, dotcover

I'm using **TeamCity 8.1.3** (currently the latest version) that includes **dotCover 2.6** for free

Love the simplicity of dotCover setup!
But can't figure out how to get cyclomatic complexity metric into TeamCity.

As far as I understand dotCover shows **cyclomatic complexity** and **HotSpots** (amazing feature!) since dotCover 2.5 when used *inside Visual Studio*.

How can I get these juicy pieces of fun(ctionality)? when running *inside TeamCity*? ))

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity 8.1.3 ships with the dotCover *console runner* which is not dotCover 2.6 gold badge edition... (unfortunately).  The console runner provides for the collection and aggregation of code coverage data only, and as far as I am aware it is not capable of aggregating CC / hotspot reports.  Up shot is, I don't think you can do what you want to do easily in TeamCity.  That said, I've not had the opportunity to work with the full version of dotCover yet.

Other options include using external static code analysis tools like [sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) (which you can integrate into your CI build, and with a bit of hackery include reports).  It has extremely rich metrics such as SQALE ratings / cyclomatic complexity / time machine reporting and lots more...  check out their [demo site](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/).

Comment: Hi Steve. Yes, Sonar is very rich, as well as NCover 4+. My goal is to get as much as possible within TeamCity without overcomplicating setup. Loved reports produced by NCover 3, but it's not supported anymore. Guess I can live without CC for now.

Comment: I couldn't agree more in keeping things simple, Sonar has now got pretty good support in TeamCity through the [meta-runner](https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack) extensions.  Pretty much a one time setup cost...

Comment: Good to know, Steve. Might very well try then Sonar runner in TeamCity.